# Implementing User specific password expiry in Django ( eg resetting every 90 days for subset of customers)

Tags: django, authentication, passwords, django-allauth, django-users

The Django app I'm building will need to accept different security policies from different User Groups. One such policy is having a customizable password-expiry rule for different users.

I've looked at django-allauth and other common authentication packages and they all have great solutions if you're looking to treat all users the same.

The one package I've found that implements some sort of user-based system is django-user-accounts. Here's the description: https://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html

However, I'd like a cleaner implementation than having to run a command for each user, any suggestions?